# Unpivoting 2 columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE TestSample
(
      Id INT ,
      StudyStartDate DATETIME ,
      StudyEndDate DATETIME ,
      DesignStartDate DATETIME ,
      DesignEndDate DATETIME ,
      StudyStartDiff INT ,
      StudyEndDiff INT ,
      DesignStartDiff INT ,
      DesignEndDiff INT
)

INSERT INTO TestSample
VALUES (1, '2010-04-22', '2012-01-17', '2012-04-09', '2012-10-08', 635, 635, 182, 182)

INSERT INTO TestSample
VALUES (2, '2014-04-15', '2015-04-30', '2015-03-30', '2016-04-11', 380, 380, 378, 378)

SELECT *
FROM TestSample
```

I need to unpivot this table to bring `StudyStartDate` and `StudyStartDatediff` under a single `Milestone` code and similarly the other columns

So my output should look like :

```
ID  Mcode   Mdate   Variance
1   XY105   2010-04-22  635
1   XY110   2012-01-17  635
1   XY205   2012-04-09  182
1   XY210   2012-10-08  182
2   XY105   2014-04-15  380
2   XY110   2015-04-30  380
2   XY205   2015-03-30  378
2   XY210   2016-04-11  378
```

The logic behind this is

- For MCode XY105 : The Mdate should be StudyStartDate  & Variance :StudyStartDiff
- For MCode XY110 : The Mdate should be StudyEndDate  & Variance :StudyEndDiff
- For MCode XY205 : The Mdate should be DesignStartDate  & Variance :DesignStartDiff
- For MCode XY110 : The Mdate should be DesignEndDate  & Variance :DesignEndDiff**

Can anyone help me with this query ?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Its for SQL-server 2008

Answer (score 0):

If you are not required to use `UNPIVOT`, would this do what you need to do?

```
SELECT ID, 'XY105' AS Mcode, ts.StudyStartDate AS Mdate, ts.StudyStartDiff AS Variance FROM dbo.TestSample AS ts
UNION 
SELECT ID, 'XY110' AS Mcode, ts.StudyEndDate AS Mdate, ts.StudyEndDiff  AS Variance FROM dbo.TestSample AS ts
UNION
SELECT ID, 'XY205' AS Mcode, ts.DesignStartDate AS Mdate, ts.DesignStartDiff  AS Variance FROM dbo.TestSample AS ts
UNION
SELECT ID, 'XY210' AS Mcode, ts.DesignEndDate AS Mdate, ts.DesignEndDiff  AS Variance FROM dbo.TestSample AS ts
```

Comment: I am looking for using Unpivot.I just put that table as a example but in real world i am joining multiple tables so i dont want to Use UNION at all.Thats y i am trying to achieve the same thing using unpivot

Answer (score 0):

```
 select   id,Dates1,Value1 from(

select Id,
StudyStartDate,StudyStartDiff,
StudyEndDate, StudyEndDiff,
DesignStartDate,DesignStartDiff,
DesignEndDate ,DesignEndDiff 
from TestSample

 ) as Ts
 unpivot 
 (Dates1 FOR Dates IN ( StudyStartDate,StudyEndDate, DesignStartDate,DesignEndDate)
) AS mrks

 unpivot 
 (Value1 FOR Value IN ( StudyStartDiff,StudyEndDiff,DesignStartDiff,DesignEndDiff)
)  AS Value

WHERE   Left(Value,10) = Left(Dates,10)
```